# How to set `org-agenda-prefix-format` before org agenda starts?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, start-up

I want to customize `org-agenda-prefix-format` before org agenda starts ：

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-prefix-format '(todo . "  %b"))
```

But if I put the previous line in my .emacs.d, Emacs will show me this error:

```
Error (use-package): org :config: Symbol's value as variable is void: org-agenda-prefix-format
```

It seems that the variable is not defined before org agenda has been started once.  How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `org-agenda-prefix-format` doesn't exist as a list so you can't add to it.  You could define it:

```
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format '((todo . "  %b")))
```

But, really this variable isn't good for anything until `org-agenda` is loaded, so just tell Emacs to `add-to-list`, but not until `org-agenda` is loaded using `with-eval-after-load`

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda 
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-prefix-format '(todo . "  %b"))
```